# Из Java FX в Maven

Tags: java, javafx, maven

Требуется собрать приложение.
 
При создании проекта выбирал **java fx**.
Как преобразовать проект в **maven** и корректно собрать в исполняемый файл?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы преобразовать в текущей версии `Intellij Idea CE`:

1. Правый клик на имени проекта в меню `Project`
2. В контекстном меню выбрать пункт `Add Framework Support...`
3. В диалоге отметить `Maven`
4. `OK`
5. Исправить имена пакетов в *.java и пути в/к *.fxml, так как у Maven'а свой взгляд, как все должно быть устроено, а конвертер проекта это не исправляет (потому для себя выбрал Gradle).

Чтобы получить переносимую программу под Windows нужно два плагина для Maven'a (также и для Gradle) — первый плагин собирает "толстый" jar (aka "fatjar", "jar with dependencies", "executable jar"), второй создает .exe-обертку.

Указав имена первого и второго плагина можно нагуглить тьму примеров `.pom` (только не забыть исправить версии плагинов на актуальные из Maven Central).

В качестве первого плагина под Maven есть несколько вариантов: `maven-assembly-plugin`, `maven-shade-plugin`, `onejar-maven-plugin`... (У меня для Gradle используется `com.github.johnrengelman.shadow`).

Есть один нюанс - если у Вас .fxml-файлы в папке с исходниками (а не в `resource`), то нужно указать, чтобы они тоже копировались в .jar-файл, так как по-умолчанию из папки с исходниками плагины берут только .java-файлы.

В качестве второго использую плагин для `launch4j` (для Maven это будет `launch4j-maven-plugin`, для Gradle — `edu.sc.seis.launch4j`).

После, как получены .jar и .exe добавляю распакованный JRE в подпапку `./jre/` рядом с .exe — комплект готов.

Можно еще и инсталятор под Windows создать — также плагином для Maven/Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

На eclipse: Правой кнопкой по проекту -> Configure ->  Convert to Maven Project